# #1062 - Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql, database, merge

i need to merge two databases 
with this

```
INSERT INTO DB1.TABLES SELECT * FROM DB2.TABLES
```

but i recierved this error

```
 #1062 - Duplicate entry '90' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to insert all but the duplicate rows, you can do so with the following SQL:

```
insert ignore into DB1.TABLES select * from DB2.TABLES;
```

Otherwise I'm unsure of your question (technically speaking, there isn't one).